# Chrome loses all my tabs after crash

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have a very annoying situation.

My chrome is in *restore previous opened tab* mode:

[image: continue where you left of]

My laptop happens to crash pretty often (I have power management issue, another exciting topic).

Most of the time, when I reopen Chrome, I get the message 'Chrome did not shutdown correctly.' And a button `Restore` that reopens everything.

But sometimes, despite clicking on `Restore`, nothing happens. It's all gone. I just can cry.

Did anyone experienced this also? I'm surprised I haven't found anything similar on the web. Should I bug-report the Chromium team? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I'd bug report it.

Comment: The problem is I have no idea how to reproduce it with confidence.